# Type inference issue for generic method

Tags: java, generics, inference

Is it possible to resolve the problem with weak inference without defining additional variables or type casts for code below?

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
    public <R> R m(Class<R> cl) {
        return null;
    }
}

GenericClass<SomeClass> v2 = new GenericClass<SomeClass>()
    .m(GenericClass.class)
    .m(GenericClass.class); // <- Object cannot be converted to GenericClass<SomeClass>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
    public <R> R m(Class<? super R> cl) {
        return null;
    }
}

GenericClass<SomeClass> v2 = new GenericClass<SomeClass>()
    .<GenericClass<SomeClass>>m(GenericClass.class)
    .m(GenericClass.class);
```

We need to fix the fact that `cl` might be an erased type (i.e., a super type of the generic type, `R`), and then we need to tell the compiler what the real type `R` is since the method argument is only indicating the super type.

The second call to `m` doesn't not need to have the generic type specified because it is inferred from the assignment.

Comment: The generic class is a third-party library class I cannot modify. But thanks anyway.

Comment: You will need to cast then.

Answer (score 0):

in order to call you method m in chain it needs to return its on class "this". In your case is GenericClass. This should work.

```
class GenericClass<T> {
    public <R> GenericClass<T> m(Class<R> cl) {
        // code to do something here
        return this;
    }
}
```

for every call to the "m" method it will return it's own class then you can call it again.

I hope that helps.